# Using javaScript variable to add css property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, var

I need to be able to count on how high a HTML element(div) should be...

I'm using this javaScript code to count and add the CSS to my "Wrapper" div:

```
var h=window.innerHeight;
var content=920;
var fix=920-h;
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height= +fix+ 'px';
```

But it isn't working at all...

Any help?

Comment: document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height= fix + 'px';

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/ubigah/2/edit) the problem.

Comment: The `+` sign that lolcat111's spot-the-difference challenge suggests removing will stop `fix` being cast to a Number before being converted to a string so it can have `"px"` appended to it. Since it is already a Number, this will make no practical difference, but will make the code slightly tidier and save you a byte.

Comment: Where are you running this JavaScript? -- if it is in your `<head>` without any domready/window.onload wrapper that will be where you problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably run this script before the body is loaded.

To load it after the body is done loading replace your code with this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var h=window.innerHeight;
  var content=920;
  var fix=920-h;
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height= +fix+ 'px';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height= fix + 'px';
```

will work.

Comment: Since the only change here is that `fix` isn't being converted to a Number, I don't see how this will work when the original code does not.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  h=window.innerHeight;
  content=920;
  fix=(content-h);
  document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height=(fix + 'px');
</script>
```

I think that's what you're looking for, as long as div ID wrapper exists.

I would think a more efficient way would be..

**(using jQuery)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    h=$(window).height;
    content=$('.content').height; //gets height of class content
    fix=(content-h);
    $('wrapper').height=fix;
  });
</script>
```

My 2 cents.

Comment: Your first solution won't make a difference, and your jQuery solution is broken... not to mention the spurious claim that it would somehow be more efficient.

Comment: Maybe not efficient as load time, but programming time. jQuery is lightweight enough to have no serious impact on page load. Other than a missing quote on the <script>, I don't know see how the JS doesn't make a difference. http://jsfiddle.net/BfBZq/

Comment: Your top solution won't make a difference because removing the unary `+` operator in the question won't help. The use of `height` in the jQuery code is incorrect, as is the `'wrapper'` selector. And jQuery isn't lightweight. It's bloated.